# How can I update the NSUserDefaults from the Settings Bundle while the app is running in background?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsuserdefaults, uilocalnotification, settings.bundle

In the settings bundle, I've got a multi choice option. So when I choose something, the app should receive the new value and use it to launch a UILocalNotification. What I've tried, only updates the values when I open the app.

```
  - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions


{  
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(defaultsChanged:)
                                                 name:NSUserDefaultsDidChangeNotification
                                               object:nil];

}
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
{

  [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]synchronize];
}
```

Comment: Your question is not clear. How does the "app receive the new value" if it is running in the background? Why do you need a `defaultsChanged:` selector?

Comment: Please also clarify what you mean by "running in the background", it could mean several things, like playing audio, providing GPS or VOIP, or performing an expiring task. You might also be meaning "suspended"

Comment: I'm using the selector to see if the user has changed any option in the settings bundle. Suspended is what I meant.

Comment: I'm guessing that you're polling the NSUserDefaults on launch, and applying settings at this phase. When a user alters settings from within the Settings.app, if those changes are detected and applied to NSUserDefaults, your app would not know it until the next launch.

Comment: Ok, thanks. So there's no way of letting the app know upon the next launch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're not truly running in the background, but `suspended` then your app will not receive any events until it is awakened by the user or relaunched. If you are running in the background you'll need to poll for changes in the settings bundle and react accordingly.